# Questions about proof of monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Folland's Real analysis, page 50, the proof of theorem 2.14 (Monotone convergence theorem), there is a step introducing $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Then a simple function $\phi$ s.t. $0\leq\phi\leq f$ is introduced, and the set $E_{n}=\{x:f_{n}(x)\geq\alpha \phi(x)\}$ is constructed. After lines of reasoning, it reaches the conclusion that $\lim_{n} f_{n}\geq \alpha\int\phi$. Now it states that since it is true for $\alpha<1$, it remains true for $\alpha=1$.

My questions are, why do we introduce $\alpha$ in the first place, can't we just let $\alpha=1$ at first? What will be missed if we actually do so? And why does the $\alpha=1$ case hold if it holds for all $\alpha<1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the argument, it is important that the union of the $E_n$ is the whole space $X$.

For a given $x$, we have $\sup_n f_n(x) = f(x) \ge \phi(x)$. This does not guarantee that there exists $n$ such that $f_n(x) \ge \phi(x)$, but it does guarantee $f_n(x) \ge \alpha \phi(x)$ for some $n$ when $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

---

Regarding your last question, you are basically asking "if $c$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $c \ge \alpha b$ holds for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$, then does $c \ge b$ hold?"